# How do I prevent line breaks on centered images without using float left?

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6KMU/3/)

I have 2 divs, one that extends 100% and another that fits in a grid. The second div has 3 images in them. I want to center those 3 images without having any line breaks.

When I use

```
#socialMediaHolder img{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}
```

It creates line breaks. Ive tried using a span and giving the span

```
span{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

But this doesnt work. I could float the images left, but then they wont be centered.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the image's display style to `inline`.

http://jsfiddle.net/J6KMU/5/

**EDIT**

Set the wrapper div style to `text-align:center`, to center the images in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/J6KMU/6/

Answer (score 3):

1. Set the `text-align: center` on `#socialMediaHolder`
2. Set `display: inline-block;` on `#socialMediaHolder img`

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/J6KMU/4/***

```
#socialMediaHolder {
    text-align: center;
}
#socialMediaHolder img {
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```